# How to strip non-numeric characters in column (WHERE clause) using MySQL 5.5

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a column `registration_number` with arbitrarily formatted values. These could be:

```
390
39B
C39(B)
39
39BC
3911
```

I need all rows that match 39. Result should be:

```
39B
C39(B)
39
39BC
```

Can I do a regexp on the WHERE column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
where registration_number regexp '(^|[^0-9])39([^0-9]|$)'
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c118903300f9bdf9665aec541bc1457e) is a db<>fiddle.